# Proof verification - If $f$ is Carathéodory, then the map $x \mapsto f(x, u(x))$ is measurable for every measurable $u$

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification, calculus-of-variations

The following is a standard theorem on the theory of Nemytskii operators, but whose proof I am finding it hard to grasp. Could someone explain it to me?

> **Theorem**: If $\Omega \subset \Bbb{R}^N$ is an open set and $f: \Omega \times \Bbb{R} \longrightarrow \Bbb{R}$ is Carathéodory, then the map $x \mapsto f(x, u(x))$ is measurable for every measurable $u : \Omega \longrightarrow \Bbb{R}$.

A Carathéodory function is such that (a) $x \mapsto f(x, s)$ is measurable for every fixed $s$ and (b) $s \mapsto f(x, s)$ is continuous for almost every fixed $x$.

The argument of the proof is as follows:

> Let $u_n(x)$ be a sequence of simple functions converging a.e. to $u(x)$. Then each $x \mapsto f(x, u_n(x))$ is measurable by (a). Now (b) implies that $f(x, u_n(x)) \to f(x, u(x))$ a.e., which gives measurability.

What I do not understand:

> - How (a) implies that $f(x, u_n(x))$ is measurable?

Here, measurability is in the Lebesgue sense.

The text I am following is de Figueiredo's *Lectures on the Ekeland Variational Principle with Applications and Detours*.

Thanks in advance and kindest regards.

**EDIT**

I think I got this, and I would very much appreciate any comments with regard to the correctness of the following argument:

For each $n$, we have 
$$
u_n = \sum_1^{k_n} \alpha_{nj} \chi_{E_{nj}}
$$
Hence
$$
f(x, u_n(x)) = \sum_1^{k_n} f(x, \alpha_{nj}) \chi_{E_{nj}}
$$
which is a sum of measurable functions, and hence is measurable.

Comment: The last equation doesn't seem right to me. If $u_n = \chi_E$ for some measurable $E\subseteq\Omega$ and if $x\in\Omega\setminus E$, then $f(x,\chi_E(x))=f(x,0)$ while the right hand side equals $f(x,0)\cdot 0 = 0$

Comment: I dont think so, we have to take into account the indicator function of the set where $u = 0$. If $F$ is this set, we would have the right-hande side equals $f(x, 1)\chi_{E}(x) + f(x, 0) \chi_F(x) = f(x, 0)$

Comment: So basically you're writing $u_n$ in such a way that $\bigcup_{j=1}^{k_n} E_{nj} = \Omega$, aren't you?

Comment: Yes, when we write simple functions we have to cover the whole set (possibly with coefficients 0)

Comment: Ok, seems right to me. Nice trick